# Permissions to access paradox db file under Windows Server 2008 x 64

Tags: permissions, odbc, oledb, paradox, windows64

I need to connect to **Paradox db** file under **Windows Server 2008 x 64**.

For this I wrote a .NET console application(32bit) with using **ODBC**.
This applications works only under admins rights (**UAC**).

But without that it throws exception:

```
ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Paradox Driver] Reserved error (-5016); there is no message for this error.
ERROR [IM006] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed
ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Paradox Driver] Reserved error (-5016); there is no message for this error.
```

So I'm trying to figure wich permissions should to give.

Giving All Permissions to **Everyone** under applications' folder, under databasefolder, under registry folder *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC* as described here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295297, under odbc* files in **%WINDIR%\System32** does not help.

Ah, also I tried to change provider to **OLE DB** (Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0) - got the same issue with rights(with using UAC all fine)

Unexpected error from external database driver (11265).

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After All I decided to use UAC rights.

It's only possible to grunt permissions to an application if it runs under sheduler (you check the ‘**Run with highest privileges**’ option when you are creating task).

As my program initialy should run under sheluder - the problem solved.